# nodejs + express + mysql Could not get any response in the backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, react-native, postman

I'm trying to make a list of foods in react native using nodejs + express + mysql, I have to make a array of objects I think to achieve it. So I make this code and run it in postman. But there is an error saying Could not get any response in the back end.

My code is based on this link: https://gist.github.com/rakawestu/d2b29bf3d0a64a44734cf47f5e34be57

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app     = express();

function con() {
  return mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'opob'
  });
}

router.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
  response.render('index', { title: 'My tutorial' });
});

app.get('/menu',function(req, res){
    var menuList = [];
    var connection = con();

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM menu', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({"status_code":500, "status_message":"internal server error"});
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var Menu = {
                    'menu_id'    : rows[i].menu_id,
                    'cat_id'     : rows[i].cat_id,
                    'menu_desc'  : rows[i].menu_desc,
                    'menu_price' : rows[i].menu_price,
                    'menu_status': rows[i].menu_status,
                }
                menuList.push(Menu);
            }
        }
    });
    connection.end();
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where is your response for menu ? You just response if error. But there is no response for else. You only push item in to your  menuList and does't reponse anything...

Comment: Do you think the link above will help? Sorry, I'm just new in this.

Comment: Did you use postman test this ? `return res.json({ menu : menuList })`

Comment: No sir, what should I do?